# Unknown Option Flag when running with sudo

Tags: sudo

Following the [examples for GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/man#examples), which is installed on Debian via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install goaccess
```

The log files are owned by www-data, the `adm` group:

```
$ admin@mycomputer:~# ls -l /var/log/nginx/
ls: cannot open directory /var/log/nginx/: Permission denied
$ sudo -i
root@mycomputer:~# ls -l /var/log/nginx/
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm   9780 Aug  1 22:11 access.log
# etc...
```

As the `admin` user I can run the basic GoAccess command succesfully using sudo:

```
$ sudo goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Cool!

```
General Dashboard - Overall Analyzed Requests                                                [Active Module 0]

  Total Requests  51 Unique Visitors 26 Referrers  0 Log Size  9.55 KiB
  Failed Requests 0  Unique Files    18 Unique 404 0 Bandwidth 0.0  B
  Generation Time 0  Static Files    0               Log File  /var/log/nginx/access.log

 Unique visitors per day - Including spiders                                                        Total: 1/1
 Hits having the same IP, date and agent are a unique visit

  26 100.00%      0.0  B 01/Aug/2016 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

 Requested files (Pages-URL)                                                                      Total: 18/18
 Top requested files - hits, percent, [bandwidth, time served]

  24 47.06%      0.0  B /
  4  7.84%       0.0  B http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=5118
  2  3.92%       0.0  B /contact/
 [F1]Help [O]pen detail view  0 - Mon Aug  1 23:38:47 2016                                 [Q]uit GoAccess 0.6
```

Without sudo (or if I run it as root, the log file is not found:

```
$ goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log

GoAccess - version 0.6 - Oct 21 2013 23:06:19

An error has occurred
Error occured at: parser.c - parse_log - 798
Message: Error while opening the log file. Make sure it exists.
```

But when I run as sudo, the options/flags *following* the log file name are not recognized:

```
$ sudo goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log -o report.html --real-time-html 
Unknown option `-o'.
$ sudo goaccess -f /var/log/nginx/access.log --no-csv-summary -o report.csv
Unknown option `--'.
```

I'm confident the *bug* is in my workflow. Can someone spin me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--no-csv-summary` flag was [added in version 0.9](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allinurl/goaccess/master/ChangeLog), from March 2015. Your version is 0.6. The [current version](https://goaccess.io/download) as of August 2016 is 1.0.2.

You may need to add the official GoAccess debian repository:

```
$ echo "deb http://deb.goaccess.io/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/goaccess.list 
$ wget -O - https://deb.goaccess.io/gnugpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install goaccess
```

Or build from source, for which you can find a guide [here](http://blog.sudoask.com/guide-to-install-and-use-goaccess-realtime-web-logs-analyzer/).

Comment: having trouble upgrading it: `apt-get install --only-upgrade goaccess` yields `goaccess is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.` Does that mean I need to add a new mirror for apt-get?

Comment: @MikeiLL what version of debian are you using? No version of debian appears to ship with 0.6.

Comment: @MikeiLL what is result of `dpkg -l goaccess`?

Comment: @roaima now that i uninstalled with apt-get and installed from source. just edited above answer to include instructions to add goaccess debian repo for apt-get.